# sys.prefix not work when install python3 from source code

Tags: python

I want to install python3 in a location different from the default, because the default location /usr/local/ already exists a python3.

So i run:

```
./configure --prefix=${USER_DEFINE_PATH} --exec-prefix=${USER_DEFINE_PATH} --enable-shared && make -j40 && make install -j40
```

After the installation finished, I ran "/${USER_DEFINE_PATH}/bin/python3" and find "import sys;sys.prefix" is not ${USER_DEFINE_PATH}.
I wonder what might be the reason for installation program ignoring the "--prefix" arg.

Well, I gave up. I choose conda.

Comment: Since you also set `--exec-pref` (which, btw, why was it necessary?), did you check for `${USER_DEFINE_PATH}/python3`?

Comment: How are you seeing what the value of `sys.prefix` is?  I assume that you're getting it by running Python.  Are you sure you're running the version of Python you just installed and not the other one that was already there?

Comment: @CryptoFool yes, I'm sure. I'm using the absolute path. And I think there is no soft link to that path.